How to schedule the container movement according to train schedule (2 PM daily)?
I have following blocks in my AnyLogic model (simplified version!).
(1) Source
arrival rate of container = 5 per hour
(2) Batch
batch size = 60 containers
(3) Sink
In the present model, batched containers are moving to SINK as soon as batch is formed and exit from BATCH block. I want to modify the model where containers move to sink only at 2 PM daily when train arrives.
I tried to do using QUEUE-EVENT-HOLD combination, but I am not able to do it.

No need to cross-post on LinkedIn and here. Use SOF for more technical questions, LinkedIn for open-ended "how to" stuff. See https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community

I’m voting to close this question because itwas already answered on LinkedIn
